# Serialized Block doesn't have all the fields of a Block

Tags: block, bitcoin-cli

`bitcoin-cli getblock 000000000003b9c88b8a4bf0bac7059913381bba300cdfddffc54a3d8c6e8105 false`

This command will give block related data in the form of Hex. This Serialized data doesn't contain certain fields like `confirmations`, `chainwork` `nextblockhash`. Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This Serialized data doesn't contain certain fields like `confirmations`, `chainwork` `nextblockhash`. Is there any reason for this?

Those fields are not actually part of a block and cannot be contained in a block.

The number of confirmations for a block constantly changes as more blocks are found on top of that block. Thus it cannot be part of a block in the serialized data.

The chainwork does not need to be included in a block because it can be dynamically calculated, unlike the other data in a block.

The `nextblockhash` cannot be known at the time of creation for a block because miners can't see the future. The `nextblockhash` cannot be known wihtout the current block already existing.